# In graphql mutation gives error in golang client

Tags: go, graphql, strapi

Actual Graphql query works fine

```graphql
mutation createQuestion($data:QuestionInput!) {  
  createQuestion(data: $data) {
    data {  
      id  
      attributes {  
        title  
        description  
        question_id  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When client side(below code in GOLANG) ran this query it's gives an issue

```go
CreateQuestion struct {
  Data struct {
    ID  graphql.ID
    Attributes struct {
      Question_id graphql.String
      Title graphql.String
      Description graphql.String
    }
  }
}
```

Passing Data like this

```go
variables := map[string]interface{} {
  "data": map[string]interface{} {
    "title": "My testFirst FbPost",
    "description": "dfsdf is the body of my first post.",
    "question_id": "35005",
  },
}
```

Gives an Error like below

> Failed to run mutation: found
> non-200 OK status code: 400 Bad Request body:
> "message":"Syntax Error: Expected Name",
> "code":"GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED",
> "stacktrace":"GraphQLError"

Trying to Posting data to Server(Strapi CMS) using [Golang client Library](https://github.com/shurcooL/graphql).

Answer (score 0):

```html
type QuestionInput map[string]interface{} 
variables := map[string]interface{}{ 
  "data": QuestionInput { 
    "title":       "My testFirst FbPost", 
    "description": "dfsdf is the body of my first post.", 
    "question_id": "35005",   
  }, 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).